# Pulling From Developer Branch When Master Isn't Used And Push To Production Comes From Developer's Branch

Tags: github, collaboration

For a project with multiple developers where one developer controls what goes to production: This developer pushes from his own branch <his_branch>, and everyone has to incorporate their changes into his branch. His branch contains his changes and the changes other developers' changes. How do I make sure I pull down his most recent branch and work from it on my local. I have tried so many different commands and approaches, with the most recent being:

1. Git clone the repository (done when I started the project)
2. Fetch his branch
3. Create a working branch <my_branch> from <his_branch>
4. git checkout -b my_branch origin/his_branch
   (I get errors)
5. Create my branch on remote
6. Fetch all including my new branch (but my new branch contains code from Master)
7. Access my branch locally, work on it, commit changes, create a pull request for him to review
   (I don't have his latest code) and there are many conflicts to resolve

I am new to GitHub and can't find a fairly straightforward answer to this question. Typically people who answer this question, make sure they provide the most complicated solution to follow to try to impress with their GitHub acumen.

Can someone provide a straightforward answer without snark, condescension, or derision?